# Keep subviews of UIScrollView from resizing?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView`, with several levels of subviews of the view returned by `viewForZoomingInScrollView`. During zooming, I want some of those subviews to resize, and others to not resize. No matter what I try, all subviews resize. On the superview of the subviews I want to not resize, I've set autoResizesSubviews = NO, and also tried `contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter`. I've also tried setting the `autoresizingMask` for all views involved to `UIViewAutoresizingNone`. Any thoughts? I can't restructure the hierarchy of subviews.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The subviews of UIScrollView's zooming view are "resized" by changing their transforms, not by changing their bounds, etc. One simple solution to your question is to catch the transform being set on the zooming view, invert it, and apply it to the subviews, canceling out the zooming transform applied by the scroll view.

In the view returned by `viewForZoomingInScrollView`, override -setTransform:, and go through all the subviews in question and apply the inverted transform:

```
- (void)setTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform 
{
    [super setTransform:transform];

    CGAffineTransform invertedTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert(transform);
    for (UIView *view in subviewsNotToBeResized) 
    {
        [view setTransform:invertedTransform];
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Don't forget to accept the best answer to your question by clicking the checkmark to its left. Also, upvote the answers that you find helpful by clicking the up arrow next to them.

Comment: I clicked the checkmark, but can't upvote since I dont' have enough reputation points.

Comment: Will this still preserve the "zooming" of the subviews positions (if not their sizes)?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 version of Andrew Madsen's excellent answer:

```
/* maintains subview size during zoom */
class NonResizingView: UIView {
    override var transform: CGAffineTransform {
        get {return super.transform}
        set {
            super.transform = newValue
            for v in subviews {
                v.transform = self.transform.inverted()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981388/pinchgesture-scale-the-its-subview-also

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` zooming is done with a transform, which will ignore your content mode and auto resizing mask.  One possible solution is to place the content that you don't want resized into a sibling view of the scroll view instead of a sub view.  Another is to try to invert the transform in real time with a `UIView` animation (see Andrew Madsen's answer).